# Problem calling each element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iteration, each

I am trying to create new div element and then change it`s position with Jquery.But J query effects only first element.I want to change all elements position with different number.

```
<div class="userList">
<?php $categories = find_category();

    foreach($categories as $category): ?>
<div id="user">
 <img id="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>" src="<?php echo $category['cat_image']; ?>" />
 <a></a>
</div>
 <?php endforeach ;?>
</div>
```

If I make in Jquery like

```
 var a= 60;
$(".userList").children().css({'left':a+'px' ,'top':a+'px'});
  a+=60;
```

This changes all `<div id="user">` to   `<div id="user" style="left: 60px; top: 60px; ">` 
But I need to make first one  left:60px top:60px and next one left:120px top:120px.

I also used .each function like

```
$(".userList").each(function(){

    $("#user").css({'left':a+'px' ,'top':a+'px'});
                a+=60;

                });
```

But this time only first `<div id="user">` changed to `<div id="user"  style="left: 60px; top: 60px; ">` And the other does not effected.

Comment: Seems to me that your are creating a lot of divs with the same `id` (user). Is that right? you might need to use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be aware that you can *not* have more than one element on a page with the same ID. You should make `user` a class instead.

With regard to the issue, you can use an `.each()` loop, and multiply `60` by the current `index` (plus one).

This will give you 60, then 120, 180, 240, etc.

```
var a= 60;
$(".userList").children().each(function( idx ) {
    var position = a * (idx + 1);
    $(this).css({'left': position ,'top': position});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The part where you set the css, is that exactly the code you're using? If so, it looks like each iteration will set a = 60. You need to define it before the start of the loop.